# “Instead of ʏᴏᴜʀ calling” vs “Instead of ʏᴏᴜ calling”

Tags: syntactic-analysis, gerund-vs-infinitive, prepositional-objects, possessive-determiners, nonfinite-verbs

Which is better:

1. Instead of **your** calling, maybe I should do it.
2. Instead of **you** calling, maybe I should do it.

I feel like the first one is the better choice here because *instead of* needs a gerund, but the second sentence seems really common.

Comment: What does being a gerund have to do with using a possessive subject? Gerunds can have either possessive or objective subjects (which is why the second sentence seems so common -- it is common because it's normal).

Comment: “Your calling” parses more strongly as one’s chosen profession (*your calling as a teacher / doctor / minister / etc*). “You calling” doesn’t have this ambiguity.